# How do I create a view(which Shows balance) that stays onscreen while I switch between tabs?

Tags: iphone, uiview, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 5 different items, each representing different views. These views represent a dialpad, contacts, call history, etc. Selecting a different tab switches to a different `UIViewController` and displays a different view, as is standard.

However, I'd like to display a persistent view that does not switch when different selections are made on the tab bar. How can I display such a view that remains onscreen at all times?
I am using View based application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if any view which need to be remain visible throughout the app, should be added to `UIWindow`

And Then to show view in particular screen use

```
yourView.alpha =1.0;
    [window bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

Hide View

```
YourView.alpha = 0.0;
```